# Python/Django value from `Form` not evaluating (or something)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a little Django website, and I'm having the following problem. I have a very simple `advanced-search/` `filter results` page where a user can select a few checkboxes and drop down menus to filter the displayed data.

However, my code is working fine for the textbox filtering, but it's not working for the boolean filtering.

This is a piece of the model:

```
class Submission(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    missing_parts = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    missing_prints = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    missing_stickers = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And this is a piece of code in the view:

```
kwargs = {}

if request.GET.get('missing_parts') is 'True':
        kwargs['missing_parts'] = True
    elif request.GET.get('missing_parts') is 'False':
        kwargs['missing_parts'] = False
    else:
        pass

submissions = Submission.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    print (request.GET.get('missing_parts'))
    print (kwargs)
```

So, what's the problem? Well, the data for 'missing_parts' is correclty received, as you can see I added a print to print the incoming request and it correclty prints either True or False. But, for some reason, the if/elif/else doesn't work. It never passes anything to the kwargs variable (I also printed that one). This same structure works completely fine for my other form inputs, only the boolean ones don't work...

I have the feeling I'm completely missing something incredibly simple...

Anyway, I hope I've explained my question/problem clearly, writing text was never really one of my best skills ;)

Comment: What are you actually sending in the GET params? Are you receiving strings, or actual booleans? And why are you comparing with `is` anyway?

Comment: I'm sending/receiving strings in the GET. But, you were right about the is. With == it's working fine. That's what I meant with something incredibly simple. So stupid I completely missed that for like an hour ._. I can't mark your solution as a correct one though, or can I? Anyway, thanks!